# Windows service terminating the service Instance when it reaches the time interval

Tags: windows, service

I developed a service which will do a particular job in 5sec of time interval.which works fine now.But latest I got new Issue that,
when the job execution time goes beyond the interval time , the service instance gets terminated and new instance gets running.

But I want like if it goes beyond the time interval , the service needs to wait until current instance execution gets finished,after that it can start new instance in interval time.

can some one help me in this issue.

Comment: I set a flag in the service to "disable" respawning of the function until it is done.  If critical, I also have a "retry after" if things fail (rarely).

Comment: What Language are you using?

Comment: yes ,same I did using a global variable in C#, but I is it works fine ?, because instance gets terminated

Comment: You add a timer (System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(MyFunction), null, 0, 5000)) and then whenever it calls, you check the flag.  The app then essentially stays alive until you destroy the time or stop the service.  You can also set the timer to infinite while you are busy and then just reset the interval.